# Getting data properly in Laravel with PHP after querying in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

So I am trying to show text in a select of a form in HTML depending of the language of the user, I am using Laravel and I have a simple way to do it:

```
Lang::get('texts.whatever');
```

That goes to texts.php file that changes 'whatever' for a proper text.

Besides, I have an associative array like this: `$dropdown = ['1'=>'France','2'=>'Germany', '3'=>'Greece', '4'=>'Portugal', '5'=>'Spain', '6'=>'United Kingdom'];`

And something like this:

```
@foreach($dropdown as $id=>$name)           
<?php
    $newArray[$id]=Lang::get('texts.'.$name);
?>
@endforeach

<?php
    $dropdown = $newArray;
?>
```

After that, I use $dropdown in my select of the form and it shows texts plus whatever it is in $name. It does not "get" the text in texts.php. However, if I change 'texts.'.$name to 'texts.yeah' (for example) it fills the select properly.

I tried `eval()`, `exec()`, etc. and I don't know what else to do. Maybe I am not using them right.

Any tips or advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How does your `texts.php` file look?

I made a little test case and it works fine for me

**lang/en/countries.php**

```
return array(
    'France' => 'France in english',
    'Germany'     => 'Germany in english',
    'Spain'     => 'Spain in english',
);
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('countries', function()
{
    $countries = [1 => 'France', 2 =>'Germany', 3 => 'Spain'];
    $dropdown = [];

    foreach ($countries as $key => $value) {
        $dropdown[$key] = Lang::get('countries.'.$value);
    }
    dd($dropdown);
});
```

returns:

```
array (size=3)
  1 => string 'France in english' (length=17)
  2 => string 'Germany in english' (length=18)
  3 => string 'Spain in english' (length=16)
```

**Even more simple routes.php example**

```
Route::get('countries', function()
{
    $countries = Lang::get('countries');
    $dropdown = [1 => $countries['France'], 2 => $countries['Germany'], 3 => $countries['Spain']];
    dd($dropdown);
});
```

returns:

```
array (size=3)
  1 => string 'France in english' (length=17)
  2 => string 'Germany in english' (length=18)
  3 => string 'Spain in english' (length=16)
```

Comment: I have a file with ALL the text in the website, not just a 'countries.php' file, but that seems to work properly. Maybe I should give it a chance.

Comment: @Zariweya: Can you add your `texts.php` file in your question? Perhaps there is something different in that file.

Comment: Or if it's really big only a snippet with the countries.